# How to prevent overflow when when using animations

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with `overflow: auto` (this can't be removed) and within it there's another div that toggles between showing and hiding using an animation when a button is clicked. The problem is that when this div moves down it causes an overflow. Keep in mind that this div must be within the container.

Example of the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/wg3jzkd6/1/

The expected result:

- Div moves down without causing overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@manuel can you move the absolute div inside the content div? if yes, try adding the `overflow: hidden;` on content div

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const absolute = document.getElementById('absolute-div')
  const absoluteClass = absolute.getAttribute('class')
  
  if(absoluteClass.includes('hidden'))
        absolute.setAttribute('class', 'absolute-div shown')
  else
    absolute.setAttribute('class', 'absolute-div hidden')
})
```

```css
@keyframes hide {
    from {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    
    to { 
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
}

@keyframes show {

    from {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    
    to { 
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 40vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.absolute-div {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  display:inline;
}

.hidden {
  animation: hide ease forwards 300ms;
}

.shown {
  animation: show ease forwards 300ms;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id='container' class='container'>
    
    <div class='content'>
    
       <button id='button'>
       SHOW/HIDE
       </button>
       
       <div id='absolute-div' class='absolute-div'>
        Hello world
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will solve the issue you are facing..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question, is that you have a container that has an extra overflow. Try using the overflow: hidden; property in your container div

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `overflow` to `hidden`

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const absolute = document.getElementById('absolute-div')
  const absoluteClass = absolute.getAttribute('class')
  
  if(absoluteClass.includes('hidden'))
        absolute.setAttribute('class', 'absolute-div shown')
  else
    absolute.setAttribute('class', 'absolute-div hidden')
})
```

```css
@keyframes hide {
    from {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    
    to { 
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
}

@keyframes show {

    from {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    
    to { 
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 40vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.absolute-div {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
}

.hidden {
  animation: hide ease forwards 300ms;
}

.shown {
  animation: show ease forwards 300ms;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id='container' class='container'>
    <div class='content'>
       <button id='button'>
       SHOW/HIDE
       </button>
    </div>
    
    <div id='absolute-div' class='absolute-div'>
      Hello world
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand, why `overflow: auto` cannot be changed. It works perfectly with the `overflow` attribute set to `hidden`.

If changing from `auto` invokes some kind of affect that is not explained here, I would kindly advise you to add this affect. But should there be such, it can probably be solved by putting this whole construct into another `div` container and isolating it, preventing any unwanted side effects.